# Using IMPORTDATA with a csv file with different numeric format than locale

Tags: google-sheets, importdata, google-sheets-import-csv

I'm using IMPORTDATA to get some Crypto Rates. My Spreadsheet has Locale settings to Spain and the data from the csv have the numeric format of United States, so I'm getting wrong numbers.

There's a way to use IMPORTDATA function on this Spreadsheet or do I need to make a new one with Locale set to United States (or change Locale setting of the current one)?

This is the formula: `=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptorates.ai/files/standard.csv")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the locale of the CSV file, like this:

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptorates.ai/files/standard.csv"; ","; "en_US")
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LnUWeKxuMpFf5vswKhtzr6UOVPitJe4KCY85k2cw1Pw/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the locale of your spreadsheet. Click File > Settings.

Regarding [IMPORTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en) it hasn't any other parameter than the URL. Instead of IMPORTDATA, you might try to use a Google Sheets Add-on, Google Apps Script or a third-party service (nowadays there are a lot).